# Are there any strict Soto Zen teachers online that I could listen to?

Tags: zen, teachers, soto

Recently, I have become interested in Soto Zen. I would like to go to a Soto Zen center, but I live to far away from one. This leaves me with the option for listening to online talks. Are there any free online dharma talks given by reliable teachers known to the Soto community. Dogen explains the features of a reliable teacher but I haven't been able to find one. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 2):

Soto Zen Dharma talks: http://livestream.com/SFZC

Shunryū Suzuki
https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4867F3D9F795268A

Answer (score 2):

Rinsen Sensei of the Buddhist Temple of Toledo has transmission in the Harada-Yasutani lineage. His Dharma talks and Teishos are posted online occasionally, all for free. He is a genuine and reliable teacher.

http://www.thedrinkinggourd.org

http://www.buddhisttempleoftoledo.org

Also check out Zen Mountain Monastery and the San Francisco Zen Center you might be able to find some free talks on there.